# difference between two monads: ErrorT e Identity v and Either e v

Tags: haskell, monads

Can someone explain difference between

```
ErrorT String Identity Integer
```

and `Either String Integer` ?

Comment: What makes you think there is one?  They're essentially the same up to some newtyping.

Answer (score 3):

(To simplify this, I'm going to answer in terms of the [`ExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html) type instead of [the deprecated `ErrorT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html).  My answer is not strictly true for `ErrorT`, but it's true modulo some annoying facts that led to the deprecation of `ErrorT`.)

The key concept to understand here is [**isomorphism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism).  To put it *very* informally, two types are isomorphic when, in spite of being superficially different, they are "essentially the same."

We can put a bit more meat on that notion by adding this concept: two Haskell types are isomorphic if both can be converted to the other in a "lossless" fashion by a pair of **inverse functions**.  In this case, `Either e a` and `EitherT e Identity a` are isomorphic because the following two functions are inverses:

```
toEither :: ExceptT e Identity a -> Either e a
toEither ma = runIdentity (runExceptT ma)

toExceptT :: Either e a -> ExceptT e Identity a
toExceptT (Left e) = throwError e
toExceptT (Right a) = return a
```

So going by the informal remarks above, what this tells you is that the two types are "essentially the same."  And the meat that the inverse functions add to this is that they prove that:

1. If you have any piece of code that uses either type, you can refactor it to use the other and the code will produce exactly the same results and behavior;
2. If you have two separate libraries, one of them uses the first type and the other uses the second, you can bridge between them by using the isomorphism functions and everything will be fine.

So what it comes down to is that in programming there are often many different ways of doing *exactly* the same thing.  In this case, `ExceptT` is a more general version of `Either`, but when you plug in `Identity` as the base monad you get something that works exactly the same as `Either` does.  We generally prefer to use `Either` in that case because then we don't have as much boilerplate, but still sometimes we find ourselves in a situation where we get `ExceptT e Identity a` and then knowing about the isomorphism helps you understand that it's not essentially different from `Either e a`.

---

Here's another way to analyze this.  The `ExceptT` type is defined like this:

```
newtype ExceptT e m a = ExceptT { runExceptT :: m (Either e a) }
```

In Haskell, a `newtype` definition is an isomorphism (the `ExceptT` constructor and the `runExceptT` function are inverses), which in this case means the following two types are isomorphic:

```
ExceptT e m a ~ m (Either e a)
```

Which means that these two are isomorphic as well:

```
ExceptT e Identity a ~ Identity (Either e a)
```

But `Identity` is also defined as a `newtype`:

```
newtype Identity a = Identity { runIdentity :: a }
```

Which means that this isomorphism holds as well:

```
Identity a ~ a
```

And therefore so do these ones:

```
Identity (Either e a) ~ Either e a
ExceptT e Identity a ~ Either e a
```

So when a library transparently defines some type as a `newtype`, it pays to notice that fact.  (And that's why library documentation in Haskell tells you whether a data types with exported constructors is a `data` or a `newtype` definition—knowing that it's a `newtype` is a big deal.)

---

Another benefit of looking at this in terms of isomorphisms is that it often helps you understand a lot of standard Haskell libraries better.  As I said above, by the `newtype` definition of `ExceptT`, the following isomorphism holds

```
ExceptT e m a ~ m (Either e a)
```

When working with a monadic type of the form `m a`, we usually call `m` the "monad" and `a` the "result type".  Looking at it through this lens, then:

1. In `m (Either e a)`, `m` is the monad and `Either e a` is the result type;
2. In `ExceptT e m a`, `ExceptT e m` is the monad and `a` is the result type.

So the `ExceptT` monad transformer is an isomorphism that allows us to "flip the perspective" on computations of type `m (Either e a)` so that we treat `a` as the result type instead of `Either e a`.  It does this by "changing the meaning" of the monad operations from what they mean in `m` to something that accounts for the "perspective flip" in question.

Answer (score 1):

By convention, [`Either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Either.html#t:Either) is used to emulate an exception system, but it is not designed for that.

That's why we use [`ErrorT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#t:ErrorT) for bigger implementations, since it comes with the [`Error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#t:Error) type, which allows the user to define more general exceptions.

However, once you run with [`runErrorT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#v:runErrorT) the monadic action of type `ErrorT e Identity a`, you get a value of type `Either e a`. So, those types are somewhat equivalent, just that `ErrorT` allows you to use functions like [`throwError`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#v:throwError) and [`catchError`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#v:catchError) instead of [`either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:either), which is less clear (especially when repeatedly used).

PS: As the documentation states, [`Control.Monad.Error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html) is deprecated, [`Control.Monad.Except`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html) instead.

Comment: `fail` is also implemented differently between them.

Comment: Thanks, haven't noticed that. However I prefer not to use `fail` because it restraints the error to be a `String`. It works for OP's case but I do not recommend it.